# Is the "dual associate" of a categorical coproduct characterized by some universal property?

Tags: category-theory, coproduct

Let $\mathcal C$ be a category with a zero-object and $(A,B)$ be a pair of objects having a  coproduct $(A\oplus B, i_A : A \to A \oplus B, i_B : B \to A \oplus B)$. We obtain unique morphisms $r_A : A \oplus B \to A$ and $r_B : A \oplus B \to B$ such that
$r_A i_A = id, r_A i_B = 0$ and  $r_B i_B = id, r_B i_A = 0$.

Let us write $(A\oplus B, i_A, i_B)^* = (A \oplus B, r_A, r_B)$ and call it the *dual associate of $(A\oplus B, i_A,, i_B)$.*

Example 1. Let $\mathcal C$ be the category of abelian groups and group homomorphims. Then $(A\oplus B, i_A, i_B)^*$ is the product of $A, B$. It is of course characterized by a universal property.

Example 2. Let $\mathcal C$ be the category of pointed topological spaces and basepoint-preserving continuous maps. Then $(A \oplus B, i_A, i_B)$ is the wedge $A \vee B$ with canonical embeddings $i_A, i_B$. Hence $(A \vee B, i_A, i_B)^* = (A \vee B, r_A, r_B)$ with canonical retractions $r_A : A \vee B \to A$ and $r_B : A \vee B \to B$. I am not aware of any universal property characterizing this system.

Questions:

1. Is there a  characterizing universal property in example 2?
2. More, generally, under what conditions on $\mathcal C$ can the dual associate be characterized by some universal property?

Comment: Is it sufficient to say the coproduct is also a product? And the correspinding maps are continuous? Perhaps e-p pairs are a solution?

Comment: For $\mathscr{G}roup$ there is no property. Given any nontrivial groups $A$ and $B$, there are nontrivial automorphisms $\varphi\colon A*B\to A*B$ with the property that $r_A\varphi = r_A$ and $r_B\varphi=r_B$ (for example, conjugation by a nontrivial element of $[A,B]$). If $(A*B,r_A,r_B)$ were haracterized by a universal property, you would necessarily have that for an automorphism $f$ of $A*B$, if $r_Af = r_A$ and $r_Bf = r_B$, then $f=\mathrm{id}$.